# Debugging Camunda BPM in Eclipse

Tags: camunda

How do I debug BPMs that are created in Eclipse using Maven projects? Every time I need to test, I have to deploy on tomcat and do the testing. But I want to debug in eclipse itself, so any pointers or steps would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is using JUnit and write testcases.

There is a [Template Project](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-engine-unittest) available on Github.

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking more visual debugger approach.

Comment: You could try out [Camunda workbench](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-workbench/wiki/Workbench-in-Unit-Tests).